# Extension scalar by Frobenius

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $p$ the characteristic of $k$ and $q=p^n$. Let $A^{(q)}=k\otimes_{k,(\ldots)^q}A$ the extension of scalar of $A$ by $(\ldots)^q:k\to k$. It is said here and there that $A^{(q)}\to A$ is $k$-linear but it seems to me that it is $A\to A^{(q)}$ that is $k$-linear: I note $.$ for the structural mulitplication by scalar and $\cdot$ for the new (that is in $A^{(q)}$):
$$ \lambda\cdot x=\lambda^q .x $$
so writing $\varphi:A\to A$ for $(\ldots)^q$ one has
$$ \varphi(\lambda.x)=\lambda^q x^q=\lambda\cdot\varphi(x) $$
so it is $\varphi:A\to A^{(q)}$ that is $k$-linear: Where is my mistake?

For mor clarity, I refer to the construction called $A^{(p)}$ [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+morphism#for_sheaves_on_)

Comment: I think this maybe the problem: I do not well understand this tensor product. Here we have $(\ldots)^q:k\to k^q$ and $\gamma:k\to A$ canonical which give $A^{(q)}=k^q\otimes_{((\ldots)^q,\gamma)}A$ so for all $\lambda\in k$, $\lambda(\alpha\otimes x)=(\lambda^q\alpha\otimes x)=\alpha\otimes(\lambda x)$

Comment: I refer to the construction called $A^{(p)}$ [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+morphism#for_sheaves_on_)

Comment: In that case $k \otimes_{k,(\ldots)^q}A:\lambda^q\alpha\otimes_{k,(\ldots)^q}x=\alpha\otimes_{k,(\ldots)^q}\lambda x$ is isomorphic to $k^{1/q}\otimes_k A: \beta\lambda\otimes_k x=\beta\otimes_k\lambda x$ through $\alpha \otimes_{k,(\ldots)^q} x \to \alpha^{1/q}\otimes_k x$. The problem I have is that there is no natural map $k \otimes_{k,(\ldots)^q}A\to A$ whereas [it](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+morphism#for_sheaves_on_) assumes there is one.
If $k=\Bbb{F}_p(t)$ then $k^{1/q}=k(t^{1/q})=k[y]/(y^q-t)$ and (for $A$ unital thus containing $k$) $k^{1/q}\otimes_k A =A[y]/(y^q-t)$.

Comment: My teacher says that in the case of a function field $K$ over a perfect field $k$ one has $K^{(q)}\simeq K^q$: it seems to be the opposite to your construction?

Comment: If you set $\lambda \alpha\otimes x=\alpha\otimes \lambda ^qx$ then the tensor product is isomorphic to $1\otimes A=A$. For a field (or an integral domain) of characteristic $p$ we always have $K^q\cong K$.